# PromQL query for getting the namespace CPU usage clusterwide

Tags: kubernetes, grafana, prometheus, promql

I am running different versions of our application in different namespaces and I have set up a prometheus and grafana stack to monitor them. I am using below promql for getting the cpu usage of different pods (as percentage of 1 core) and the value that it returns is matching the values that I get from the `kubectl top pods -n namespace`:

```
sum (rate (container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{id!="/",namespace=~"$Namespace",pod=~"^$Deployment.*$"}[1m])) by (pod)*100
```

The problem is I want to get the total cpu usage of all pods in a namespace cluster-wide and I tried different queries but the values that they return is not matching the total cpu usage that I get from the above promql or `kubectl top pods -n namespace`.

The promql queries that I tried:

```
sum (rate (container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{namespace=~"$Namespace",pod=~"^$Deployment.*$"}[1m])) by (namespace)
sum (rate (container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{namespace=~"$Namespace",pod=~"^$Deployment.*$"}[1m]))
```

I am using the `Singlestat` for this and also at `visualization` from `Value` section I tried different `show` methods such as Average, total, current but non returned the correct value.

My question is how I can get the total cpu usage of all the pods in a namespace cluster-wide?

Comment: Could you please try with this one: `sum (rate (container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{id!="/",namespace=~"$Namespace",pod=~"^$Deployment.*$"}[1m])) / sum (machine_cpu_cores{}) * 100`

Comment: Thank you for your comment. As I wrote in my question I am using `sum (rate (container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{id!="/",namespace=~"$Namespace",pod=~"^$Deployment.*$"}[1m])) by (pod)` to get the pods cpu usage and it works correct for each pod separately but the problem is I want the sum of all pods cpu usage and the value that I get from this is not equal to the value that I get by summing all pods cpu usages.

Answer (score 2):

The following PromQL query should return summary per-namespace CPU usage across all the pods in Kuberentes (the CPU usage is expressed in the number of used CPU cores):

```
sum(rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{container!=""}[5m])) by (namespace)
```

The `{container!~""}` filter is needed for removing CPU usage metrics for `cgroups hierarchy`, since these metrics are already included with non-empty `container` labels.

The query uses the following PromQL functions:

- [sum()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#sum)
- [rate()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#rate)

Answer (score 0):

I have made some research and found few answers that could suit your needs:

1. In order to simply monitor CPU usage at cluster level use:
   `sum (rate (container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{id="/"}[1m])) / sum (machine_cpu_cores) * 100`
2. If you want to see %CPU usage for a namespace you'll need to calculate namespace CPU usage first and than divide it by the available CPU in a cluster. It would look like this:
   `sum (rate (container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{namespace="$Namespace"}[1m])) / sum(machine_cpu_cores) * 100`
3. You can also use Prometheus' arbitrary labels in order to calculate CPU usage of a namespace. More details can be found [here](https://www.weave.works/blog/aggregating-pod-resource-cpu-memory-usage-arbitrary-labels-prometheus/).
4. Finally you can try [Prometheus exporter](https://github.com/cloudworkz/kube-eagle).

Please let me know if that helped.